# Python regex, how to match a string for n times of occurrences

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the line that contains word 100.00% for 3 occurrences.

e.g

```
some string 100.00% foo 100.00% 100.00%
some string  99.91%  foo 100.00% 99.91%
some string 100.00%100.00%100.00%
```

So line 1 and 3 should all be matched.

However, my following regex seems only to match the case that has 100.00% repeated for 3 times. (Only match line 3)

```
re.search(r"([1][0][0]\.[0][0][%]){3}",string)
```

I wonder how should I do to match line 1 as well?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: It only matches the bottom line because they are all touching. But line 1 has stuff in between, like spaces and `foo`. Your current regex doesn't account for that.

Comment: how about this? re.search('100\.00%.*100\.00%.*100\.00%', string)

Comment: @Shiping This will match strings that have `100.00%` repeated more than 3 times

Comment: @silel yes, it'll match lines with 3 or more 100.00%. the post is not clear if it has to be exact 3 occurrences of 100.00%.

Comment: @Shiping, Sorry for not clarifying my question. I want to match exact 3 occurrences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternative that requires a *simpler* regular expression is to find all substrings that match `100.00%` and test if the count == 3.

example

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'100\.00%')
texts = ['some string 100.00% foo 100.00% 100.00%',
         'some string  99.91%  foo 100.00% 99.91%',
         'some string 100.00%100.00%100.00%']

matches = [i for i, t in enumerate(texts)
           if len(re.findall(p, t)) == 3]
# matches = [0, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

Halemur Ali's answer is much cleaner than this one which I leave only for completeness.

The notation `{3}` is merely a shortcut, you can always replace it by expanding the repeated sequence. To match line where the sequence `100.00%` appears exactly 3 times, you can use:

```
"^(?:(?!100\.00%).)*(?:100\.00%(?:(?!100\.00%).)*){3}$"
```

This uses [negative-lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

It can be read this way:

- `^` start of the line
- `(?:(?!100\.00%).)*` any character (zero or more), until a `100.00%` sequence
- `(?:100\.00%` the `100.00%` sequence
- `(?!100\.00%).)*` followed by any character (zero or more) until a `100.00%` sequence
- `{3}` repeated 3 times
- `$` end of line

Consider taking a look at python's documentation of the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

*Note: brackets are not necessary to match a single character.*

Comment: Both of you and Halemur Ali's answer solved my problem, and thanks a lot for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`r'(100\.00%.*){3}'` should also do the trick, and is readable, concise, and (I think) performant.

Comment: maybe `r'(100\.00%.*){3}'`

Comment: @HaleemurAli yeah thanks, edited in the radix and forgot to escape t_t

Comment: This will also match lines with more than 3 `100.00%` sequences.

Comment: just like @silel said. It will match more than 3 occurrences, and I would like to match exact 3 times